# setting up peer to peer networking for online multiplayer game

Tags: javascript, network-programming, p2p

I am creating a turn based multiplayer strategy game with javascript and html, I am at the point where I am creating the multiplayer functionality. I looked at the options and due to that fact that there will only be max 8 players at a time, and it is turn based so only one player will be manipulating the game at a time, I've concluded that peer to peer would be a good solution. However I cant find any articles detailing how to set something like this up.

All tutorials and articles I have found explain what peer to peer networking is, challenges and possible solutions, but nothing detailing exactly how to set up connections between peers etc. The articles/tutorials I have found that do go into detail revolve around a p2p client being downloaded to the users computer. I don't want the user to have to download anything. I'd like users to be able to set up a game on the site and use the connection information of the players who join the game be used to run it peer to peer via the javascript that has been loaded in their browser.. maybe I'm not understanding how peer to peer works? is this possible?

I am looking for any articles, tutorials whatever that will help me achieve this, or if someone can explain, I wont turn down the explanation..  or if I am misunderstanding how things work and its not possible, that would be good to know too.

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec / too broad. See also: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67738/limitations-of-p2p-multiplayer-games-vs-client-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options.  Ultimately though if the computers are not on the same network you'll need a server in the middle to help handle routing and introducing new connections.

1. NodeJS server that opens a web socket with each of the clients and can negotiate communications as well as push data from the server to the client (which you'll want).
2. WebRTC is a protocol with an api available on latest browsers and sites like: http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/ have loads of resources and libraries available to help you get started.
3. You can utilize any of a myriad of messaging servers such as XMPP, STUN, ActiveMQ (my favorite), etc. and can follow typical pub/sub patterns while utilizing web sockets, rtc, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I wish I had the option of using NodeJS.. unfortunately its not available to me at the moment.. checking out the other resources now though!

Comment: NodeJS is not necessary, it just makes working with web sockets super easy.  You can utilize web sockets with php/apache as well.